# Java code not calling necessary methods

Tags: java

Hello you fine people of this website. Now I have begun to learn Java as I wish to pursue a future in programming. Recently I ran into a bug that seemed to defy all logic, and no matter how long I sat there trying to determine every possible reason, I was not able to find one.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Answer extends Main {

private static long numerator;
private static long preNumerator;
private static long denominator;
private static long preDenominator;
private static long remainder;
private static String result;

// private static long answer;

// public Line(){
// super();
// }
//
// public Line(long numerator, long denominator, long remainder){
// super(numerator, denominator, remainder);
// }
public Answer() {
    this(0, 0);
}

public Answer(long n, long d) {
    numNegativeCheck(n, d);
}

public static void numNegativeCheck(long n, long d) {
    if (n < 0 || d < 0) {
        numerator = n * 2;
        numerator = n - numerator;
        denominator = d * 2;
        denominator = d - denominator;
        remainderCalculate(numerator, denominator);

    } else {
        if (n > 0 || d > 0) {
            remainderCalculate(n, d);

        } else {
            if (n > 0 || d < 0) {
                preNumerator = n * 2;
                numerator = n - preNumerator;
                preDenominator = d * 2;
                denominator = d - preDenominator;
                remainderCalculateNeg(numerator, denominator);

            } else {
                if (n < 0 || d > 0) {
                    remainderCalculateNeg(n, d);

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void remainderCalculateNeg(long n, long d) {
    remainder = n / d;
    remainderCheckNeg(n, d, remainder);
}

public static void remainderCheckNeg(long n, long d, long r) {
    if (r == 0) {
        calculationsRZeroNeg(n, d, r);
    } else {
        calculationsRNeg(n, d, r);
    }
}

public static void calculationsRNeg(long n, long d, long r) {
    numerator = n / remainder;
    denominator = d / remainder;
    displayNeg(numerator, denominator, r);
}

public static void calculationsRZeroNeg(long n, long d, long r) {
        numerator = n / d;
        denominator = 1;
        displayNeg(numerator, denominator, r);
}

public static void displayNeg(long n, long d, long r){
    if (r == 0){
        result = "The answer is: " + numerator;

    }else{
        result = "The answer is: " + numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static void remainderCalculate(long n, long d) {
    if (n > d) {
        remainder = n % d;
        remainderCheck(n, d, remainder);

    } else {
        remainder = d % n;
        remainderCheck(n, d, remainder);
    }
}

public static void remainderCheck(long n, long d, long r) {
    if (r == 0) {
        calculationsRZero(n, d, r);
    } else {
        calculationsR(n, d, r);
    }
}

public static void calculationsR(long n, long d, long r) {
    numerator = n / remainder;
    denominator = d / remainder;
    displayFraction(n, d);
}

public static void calculationsRZero(long n, long d, long r) {
    if (n > d) {
        numerator = n / d;
        denominator = 1;
        displayFull(n, d);

    } else {
        denominator = d / n;
        numerator = 1;
        displayFull(n, d);
    }
}

public static void displayFull(long n, long d) {
    if (n > d) {
        result = "The answer is: " + numerator;

    } else {
        result = "The answer is: " + numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
}

public static void displayFraction(long n, long d) {
    result = "The answer is: " + numerator + "/" + denominator;
}
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public long getNumerator() {
    return this.numerator;
}

public long getDenominator() {
    return this.denominator;
}

public String getResult() {
    return this.result;
}

}
```

This code may be a bit messy but I'll explain the simple gist of it. I am making a little program that can reduce fractions. It can handle negatives, both in the numerator and denominator position, and if the denominator is 1, it is not displayed, rather the numerator is displayed as a whole number (fancy, I know). The numNegativeCheck simply checks which parts of the fraction are negative, if any of them are actually negative, and it works fine. The second part with all the neg's is simply methods that have to do with negative numbers, and the last part is for positive numbers.

On to the issue: The program seems to work well, but I've noticed that if I input a positive numerator (ex. 32) and a negative denominator (ex. -4), it displays "-8/1". Now although this is correct a large part of what my program does is the fact that it displays just the numerator if the denominator is 1, so it should have displayed "-8".

When the negative calculation methods have finished, they are directed to the negative display method. However, for some odd reason the "displayFraction" method is called, which is for an entirely different section. I have thought about this for the past hour, just sitting at my computer screen and going through the code, line by line, multiple times, unable to come up with a solution for as to why when I tell it that I want to call the "displayNeg" method it calls something else. If anybody has a solution I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you used a debugger or a "poor-man's debugger" (`System.out.println("foo variable = " + foo);`) to check the state and behavior of your code as it runs?

Comment: Using a debugger will show you what your program is really doing any why, not what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Tip: To change the sign of an int, just do `remainder = -remainder;`. You do not need to substract twice the original value.

Comment: A side effect of being new to all this is that I wanted to debug but I don't know how. I am using Eclipse and have looked all over the web but it doesn't seem to work. Also I don't know if this is important but the entire program is running in a JOptionPane.

Comment: @SJuan76 I know this but I find that my code is much easier to read if I do it by subtracting twice.

Comment: @ViliMilner - Unfortunately, almost nobody else will.  In fact, most people will probably assume you're trying for _something else_.  Other notes - try to use more local variables (variables declared inside of methods), and especially avoid `static` variables if you can.  Concentrate more on passing in values/value objects that contain the information you need.  Try to label method parameters as to how they're being used, and eliminate unused parameters.

Comment: When I write short code and I cannot find the bug I usually just rewrite the entire thing, the design gets better and bugs fewer.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) for a tutorial on using Eclipse's debugger.